# Assign implementation based on assembly

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I have a couple generic interfaces and implementations in a common infrastructure assembly.  Examples:

```
AlphaRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
BetaRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
```

I'm working on a modular architecture so each subsystem has its own assembly which leverages this common library.  Each repository has a constructor which takes in an IDbContext.  Each subsystem implements and extends IDbContext.  Is it possible, through structuremap, to do something along the lines of:

- For Assembly A, For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(AlphaRepository<>)), Use AlphaContext for IDbContext.
- For Assembly B, For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(BetaRepository<>)), Use
  BetaContext for IDbContext

I'd like to split these into different registries as well (i.e. AlphaRegistry and BetaRegistry).  All of these would be wired up in a static IoC class where the container is initialized.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE (in response to Steven's question):**

Not necessarily; I've build them to be flexible enough to either share a database or use separate databases.  They both share a base DbContext : IDbContext.  The issue is that the AlphaUnitOfWork takes in a AlphaContext then passes that to the EfUnitOfWork base as a IDbContext.  The issue is instructing structuremap to use AlphaContext when operating in the Alpha assembly and BetaContext when using Beta assembly classes.  As a work around (in this case), I've typed IDbContext then used the Forward>() syntax.  Working thus far but I'd like to do this with other classes (i.e. ILogger implementations based on calling assembly so Alpha can store in DB and Beta can store in NoSQL) without having to make them generics.

Comment: Do `AlphaContext` and `BetaContext` point at the same database, or at least point at database with the exact same database schema?

Comment: Updated original question because my response was too long.  Thanks Steven!

Comment: If `AlphaRepository<T>` breaks when a `BetaContext` context is injected, you are violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and this is the root of your trouble. Instead, give each context its own abstraction and let each repository depend on that abstraction, or depend on the concrete type directly. This solves the LSP violation, and solves your registration troubles completely.

Comment: The AlphaRepository would not break if BetaContext was passed in.  As long as it is an IDbContext, then everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the valid point that Steven raised, I think you can solve this problem along the following lines...

In a given registry you would register `DbContext` and `Repository` as named instances with the name the same as the Assembly name. The issue with that may be that the naming does not work with open generic definitions, a thing that I cannot check right now.

For injecting those in the corresponding consumers, you'd then configure which named instance to use for some given ctor argument. You would derive the name from the assembly of the type that you are just configuring.